# Excel formula to count cumulative numbers in an adjacent cell based on 2 criteria

Tags: excel

I have a question about how to add a running total column to an already existing data set that contains information stored as a series of 0s and 1s. I would like this Excel formula to take into account 2 conditions (Col A & Col B) in it's summation (Col C) and repeat itself once it finds new criteria. Here is an example of what I'm hoping for:

Client No. | Salesperson | Success | [NEW] Running Total of Success
8242015 | Bob | 0 | 0
8252015 | Bob | 1 | 1
8262015 | Bob | 0 | 1
8272015 | Bob | 1 | 2
8272015 | Jack | 0 | 0
8282015 | Jack | 0 | 0
8292015 | Jack | 1 | 1
8302015 | Jack | 1 | 2
8312015 | Jack | 0 | 2

Is there a way for me to easily add column D as a formula and drag it down the data set of ColA:ColC?

Comment: Yes. There is. But what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with how your data is laid out; this is all you need in column D (starting at D2, assuming D1 is blank so that it can be read as "0".

```
=IF(AND(A2=A1,B2=B1),D1+C2,C2)
```

And that's it. It checks to see if the data in columns A & B matches the row above - if it does, it adds the current 'C' row to the running total in D above. If it doesn't, then it just starts at the value in the current 'C' row.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could use the `SUMIF` formula.  Assuming your data starts in the second row and exists in columns A-C, in cell D2 start here:

```
=SUMIF($B$2:B2,B2,$C$2:C2)
```

Then drag the formula down.

Comment: If you want to go this route, you should convert to SUMIFS, and use both columns A & B (in case there is a duplicate of the value in column B, for 2 different values in column A). Like so: SUMIFS($C$:C2,$A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2,B2)